# How to upload a Salesforce File using REST API properly?

Tags: rest, api, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

`GET /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0000v00000MFIVgAAP/VersionData` from this request I will get binary file content, but how can I use this content to recreate the file properly (using request to `POST /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion`)?

I uploaded **.docx** through the UI and fetch its content. 
Then I uploded that content using the request:

**Endpoint**

> /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion

**Headers**

> Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary_string
>            Accept: application/json

**Body**

```
--boundary_string 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content"; 
Content-type: application/json

{"PathOnClient":"MyFile.docx"}

--boundary_string 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="MyFile.docx"

Binary data from the request to GET /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0000v00000MFIVgAAP/VersionData.

--boundary_string--
```

The request above is executed with a success status code, and the file was created successfully, but when I downloaded this file from UI, it became damaged :(
There may be something in the request body that I missed (but I don’t know what exactly is wrong), so the file creates damaged.

Comment: Take a look at [salesforce.se] SE, there are a number of questions and answers on this topic over there.

Comment: If you find something, please share this information here. I did not find anything that could help me solve my problem. If you will be so kind, please do so.

Comment: Here's [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219877/correct-approach-uploading-file-using-rest-api-file-size-100-mb)

Comment: Thanks. But how can it help me solve my problem? 
I`m able to upload the file via REST API. After downloading its content from the UI, the file is damaged. How to fix this?

Comment: You're able to complete a REST operation and receive a status code in HTTP response. Does that mean your overall attempt is successful? Clearly that is still an open question. Since this type of question is very Salesforce-specific, SO isn't the best place for it...but perhaps someone here will help you.

Comment: I understand your point. 
There may be something in the request body that I missed (but I don’t know what exactly is wrong), so the file creates damaged.

Comment: are you able to find out what is the problem. I am also facing the same problem. I can upload a txt file but all other types of files are corrupted

Comment: @PavloMykhailyshyn is this resolved?

Comment: yeah
It was the problem in a body.
Using my own application and transferring data in proper format (binary format) everything works fine.